# PowerShell JSON: How to find out, if key exists=

Tags: json, powershell

I work with Powershell 5.1
I try to use a (simple) JSON-File as a letter box between scripts.
So at the beginning of the script I read the File, modify it and store it at the end.
For Example the following file

```
{
    "A":  {
              "April":  "4",
              "August":  "8"
          },
    "J":  {
              "January":  "1",
              "July":  "7"
          }
}
```

For better handling I wrote a Read-Value and a Write-Value function. In this Example the Read-Value shows my problem: the function doesn't find the Parameter "Name".

```
$config_file_full = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'months.json'
$config_json = Get-Content -Raw -Path $config_file_full | ConvertFrom-Json

function Read-Value {
    param (
        [string]$Subject,
        [string]$Name
    )
    # $result = $null

    if (-not ($config_json.PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $Subject)) {
        Write-Host "READ NO MATCH for SUBJECT " $Subject
        $result = $null
    } elseif (-not ($config_json.PSObject.Properties.$Subject.Name -contains $Name)) {
        Write-Host "READ NO MATCH FOR SUBJECT " $Subject "NAME " $Name
        $result = $null
    } else {
        $result = $config_json.$Subject.$Name
        Write-Host "READ NO MATCH FOR SUBJECT " $Subject "NAME " $Name "VALUE <" $result ">"
    }

    return $result
}

$a = Read-Value -Subject 'A' -Name 'April'
Write-Host "<" $a ">"

$config_json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path $config_file_full
```

The Result is

```
READ NO MATCH FOR SUBJECT  A NAME  April
<  >
```

What is wrong? The elseif- Condition does't work as expected.
Thank you

Comment: There are a few fun bits there. You may find this line works better: `} elseif (-not ($config_json.PSObject.Properties[$Subject].Value.PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $Name)) {`

This is somewhat down to the PSNoteProperty not working with dot-notation like that (being closer to a hashtable than a set of named properties, amusingly), and then the "value" within that being an object - so even if the dot-notation worked, you were checking a level too high (checking for "April" where the name was "A").

Comment: This seems to work, even if I don't have any idea what is happening here ... to encapsulate this into a readable function is the best I can do. Thank you for your answer. Make a answer so that I can commit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[James Ruskin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77501573/712649) will solve your problem, but it can be done a little more elegantly if you replace your `if/elseif/else` statement with 2 separate `if` blocks and then use `return` to "exit early" on error conditions:

```
function Read-Value {
    param (
        [string]$Subject,
        [string]$Name
    )
    if (-not ($config_json.PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $Subject)) {
        Write-Host "READ: No match for SUBJECT '$($Subject)'"
        return
    }

    # if we've reached this point it must mean the subject exists, assign to a variable
    $subjectObject = $config_json.PSObject.Properties[$Subject].Value

    if (-not ($subjectObject.PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $Name)) {
        Write-Host "READ: Matched Subject '$($Subject)' but not Name '$($Name)'"
        return
    }

    Write-Host "READ: Matched Subject '$($Subject)' and Name '$($Name):<$($result)>"
    $config_json.$Subject.$Name
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here.

- PSObject.Properties here is a collection of `PSPropertyInfo` instances (corrected thanks to @mklement0), which don't allow you to address each property using dot-notation as you have attempted.
- Even when you get to the `$Subject` you want to check, the `Name` property contains the name of that Subject and not the `$Name` you were checking for.

This should work better:

```
function Read-Value {
    param (
        [string]$Subject,
        [string]$Name
    )
    if (-not ($config_json.PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $Subject)) {
        Write-Host "READ: No match for SUBJECT '$($Subject)'"
    } elseif (-not ($config_json.PSObject.Properties[$Subject].Value.PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $Name)) {
        Write-Host "READ: Matched Subject '$($Subject)' but not Name '$($Name)'"
    } else {
        Write-Host "READ: Matched Subject '$($Subject)' and Name '$($Name)': <$($config_json.$Subject.$Name)>"
        $config_json.$Subject.$Name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To ***complement* the existing, helpful answers**:

- with a **potentially *simpler*, but *not fully equivalent* solution**:

  - PowerShell generally allows you to **use expressions such as variable references as property names, e.g. `$config_json.$Subject`**
  - IF you don't need to distinguish between the *existence* of a property and  whether it *exists but contains `$null`*, you can use this ability to simplify your function:

    ```
    function Read-Value {
      param (
        [string]$Subject,
        [string]$Name
      )
      Set-StrictMode -Version 1
      if ($null -eq ($subject = $config_json.$Subject)) {
        Write-Host "READ NO MATCH for SUBJECT " $Subject
      } elseif ($null -eq ($result = $subject.$Name)) {
        Write-Host "READ NO MATCH FOR SUBJECT " $Subject "NAME " $Name
      } else {
        Write-Host "READ MATCH FOR SUBJECT " $Subject "NAME " $Name "result <" $result ">"
        $value # Output
      }
    }
    ```
- with a detailed explanation of **why `$config_json.PSObject.Properties.$Subject` *doesn't* work**, unlike `$config_json.PSObject.Properties[$Subject]`, even though it tries to use the same technique: see below.

---

The `.Properties` property of the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views) is a rich source of reflection for any object.

It contains a **collection of [`System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo) instances**<sup>[1]</sup> each containing information about a property of the object, notably `.Name` and `.Value`.
The **collection itself is of type [`System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoCollection-1)**<sup>[2]</sup>

Due to PowerShell's convenient [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature, you were able to use `$config_json.PSObject.Properties.Name` in order to retrieve the `.Name` property values from the *elements* of that collection; that is, this expression is equivalent to:
`$config_json.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }`

For this reason, `$config_json.PSObject.Properties.$Subject` did *not* work, because the `PSPropertyInfo`-derived instances in the collection have no property named `A`, for instance.

However:

- **`PSMemberInfoCollection<T>` implements a dictionary-*like* lookup mechanism** via its [parameterized `.Item` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoCollection-1.Item), which allows retrieval of a `PSPropertyInfo`-derived element via the value of its `.Name` property, which can be **accessed via *index* notation**; e.g.:

  ```
  # OK -> [PSNoteProperty] instance describing the .Bar property.
  # Append .Value to extract the value only.
  ([pscustomobject] @{ Foo=1; Bar=2 }).psobject.Properties['Bar']
  ```
- However, because **it *isn't a true dictionary*, due to not implementing the [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary) interface**, the **normally equivalent *dot notation* is *not* supported**.

  ```
  # !! $null - dot notation does NOT work here: looks for a .Bar
  # !! property on every [PSNoteProperty] element, via member-access enumeration.
  ([pscustomobject] @{ Foo=1; Bar=2 }).psobject.Properties.Bar

  # By contrast, with a true dictionary such as [hashtable], index notation and
  # dot notation are largely interchangeable:
  # OK -> 2
  @{ Foo=1; Bar=2 }['Bar']
  # OK -> 2
  @{ Foo=1; Bar=2 }.Bar
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Technically, they are instances of types *derived* from this abstract class, such as [`System.Management.Automation.PSProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSProperty) or, in the case at hand, [`System.Management.Automation.PSNoteProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSNoteProperty).</sup>

<sup>[2] Technically, it is of type `[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoIntegratingCollection<T>]`, a *non-public* type that *derives from* said type.</sup>